# Loading contents of a remote file as a blob and uploading it via JavaScript as a file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get the contents of a remote file via php using an $.ajax request. I then want to append that data to a form as a file and upload it. I'm close, but not all the way there. Anyone have any advice? I can display an image in the browser when I encode it, but when I upload it either as raw unencoded data or as base64 the file I get on the server is unreadable.

getfilecontents.php

```
$path = 'testimg.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
echo $base64;
```

main.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var filedata = -1;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "getfilecontents.php", dataType: "text", success: function (data) {
                        filedata = data;
                        showimg(filedata);
                        doUpload();
                    }
                });
            });

            function showimg(fileis) {
                var myFile = new File([fileis], "foo.jpg", {
                    type: 'image/jpg'
                });
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(myFile);
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.file = myFile;
                    img.src = fileis;// e.target.result;
                    img.className = "thumb";
                    $("body").append(img);

                }
            }

            function doUpload() {
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("uploadform1"));
                var myFile = new File([filedata], "strava.jpg", {
                    type: 'image/jpg'
                });
                formData.append("fileToUpload", myFile);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "uploadfile.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: "HTML",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success " + data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test3.php" method="post" id="uploadform1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

uploadfile.php

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

Comment: When you get the contents of the image file and you are displaying the same, save it as a file on the server. Then send the image location via form hidden input. And upon form submission, move the file to a proper location.

Comment: Two different servers. In real life I would not control the uploadfile.php server.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php Also, use your browser console to see if the data that gets send looks like it makes sense, or if it is rather obvious that something is missing/wrong (like messed up boundaries, wrong Content-Types, etc.)